# Find next birthdays to celebrate

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an user model in my phoenixframework project with a birthday attribute which holds a Timex.Ecto.Date value.

```
defmodule MyProject.User do
  use MyProject.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :active, :boolean
    field :birthday, Timex.Ecto.Date
    field :login, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :nickname, :string

    timestamps
  end

  # ... changeset and other code ...
end
```

Now I try to find all users who will celebrate their birthday within the next 30 days from now. Assume there is a user record with date of birth at 1980-02-01. Today is 2017-01-13.

What I have now:

```
{:ok, date_from} =
  Timex.local
  |> Timex.Ecto.Date.cast

{:ok, date_to} =
  Timex.local
  |> Timex.add(Timex.Duration.from_days(30))
  |> Timex.Ecto.Date.cast

MyProject.Repo(from(u in MyProject.User, where: u.birthday >= ^date_from, where: u.birthday <= ^date_to))
```

Because of the year it can't work. How do I have to build the ecto query?

Comment: While I do not know the answer, it may be more useful to ask the community for the database you are using. e.g., ask a SQL tagged question if you are using a SQL database. Once you know how to do the raw query, it should be fairly straight forward to translate that into ecto.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to say that I'm using a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, I'd use `age` to get the interval between the birth date and now, truncate it to just the year, add it to the birth date to get the next birthday, and then see if it's within the next 30 days:

```
postgres=# select current_date;
    date
------------
 2017-01-14
(1 row)

postgres=# select '2000-01-20'::date + date_trunc('year', age('2000-01-20'::date)) + interval '1 year' <= current_date + interval '30 days';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select '2000-02-20'::date + date_trunc('year', age('2000-02-20'::date)) + interval '1 year' <= current_date + interval '30 days';
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

With Ecto, this should look like (untested):

```
from(u in User, where: fragment("? + date_trunc('year', age(?)) + interval '1 year' <= current_date + interval '30 days'", u.birthday, u.birthday))
```

It's also trivial now to change the interval to `'1 month'` and PostgreSQL will correctly add the number of days in the current month and give you the users that have their birthday within 1 month instead of within 30 days.

Comment: OP: this answer is definitely better than mine.

Comment: This is a very good solution and it works if I use it like you suggested. But if I use another parameter, just to be flexible, it fails: `days = 30; from(u in User, where: fragment("? + date_trunc('year', age(?)) + interval '1 year' <= current_date + interval '? days'", u.birthday, u.birthday, ^days))` 
This results in an Error: `(ArgumentError) parameters must be of length 0 for query %Postgrex.Query`

Comment: @guitarman try `interval '1 day'  * ?`. Also check out this answer I wrote a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41571998/320615.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of any possibility to do that explicitly with `Ecto`, but the following raw SQL should be working for MySQL (`WHERE` clause only):

```
WHERE DAY(bd) > DAY(NOW()) AND MONTH(db) = MONTH(NOW()) 
   OR DAY(bd) <= DAY(NOW()) AND MONTH(db) = MOD(MONTH(NOW()), 12) + 1
```

For PostgreSQL change `DAY(XXX)` to `EXTRACT(DAY FROM XXX)`:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM bd) > EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW()) ....
```

These clauses might be used in `Ecto` fragments as is.

Comment: Ok, now I read about fragments in ecto queries. I will try it out later together with your answer.

Comment: Damn, I forgot to mention fragments in my answer, but you seem to have a power to read between lines :)

Comment: Technically this would return birthdays in the next 1 month, not 30 days :)